# How do I measure a string that will be drawn with SpriteBatch?

Tags: c#, monogame, text

Is there a way to measure width and height of an ever-changing string (a player's score, specifically)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given

```
SpriteFont font;
```

Do this:

```
Vector2 size = font.MeasureString("Your String Here");
```

Comment: As a note, the width is what you would expect, the edge of the left most character to the edge of the right most character. However, the height is the line height which means it is not dependent on the characters in the string. for example measuring 'a', 'g', or 'I' all would return the same height although the widths would be different.